# Memory Management in C++: Differences in allocating shared_ptr using new vs make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I'm used to allocate shared pointer this way:
`std::shared_ptr<Person> ptr = std::make_shared<Person>("Name", 27);`
As I saw in other project, they allocate the pointer in a different way, and I want to understand the memory management behind each one.

```
1. std::shared_ptr<Person> ptr(new Person("Name", 27));
2. std::shared_ptr<Person> ptr = std::shared_ptr<Person>(new Person("Name", 27));
3. std::shared_ptr<Person> ptr = std::make_shared<Person>("Name", 27);
```

All of these options manage their memory without needed to de delete them manually ?

Comment: #1 and #2 are the same.  #3 has the advantage of combining the allocation of the shared pointer's *control block structure* and the *Person* into a single allocation.  (Usually an advantage; can be a disadvantage if the *Person* is very large and there are a lot of weak_ptr keeping the memory allocated for extended period of time.)  iirc, `enable_shared_from_this` relies on `make_shared` to be initialized correctly (I may be mistaken... I only use `make_shared`).

Comment: Functionally, the three options are equivalent, and the object managed by `ptr` will cease to exist when `ptr` does.   `make_shared()` is simply a helper function that constructs an object from supplied arguments, and wraps it in a `shared_ptr`.       Generally, using `make_shared()` is considered less error prone  (e.g. there is no opportunity for YOU to use operator `new` incorrectly in any way - such as due to a typo - since it takes care of all that).

Comment: As a side note, if you're making a class that must only be allocated through a factory function returning a `shared_ptr` (so you guarantee that all instances are `shared_ptr`), you might want to make your constructor private. Which means `std::make_shared` can't call it... but you can still `new` it in your factory function.